# Template function taking as argument 1 of the other template functions inside same class

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, function-pointers

The objective I'm aiming to is **creating a function**, among all the "operative" functions, **that takes as 3rd argument**, **one of the other functions** inside the class. Say we have 4 template functions that respectively sum(`doAdd`), subtract(`doSub`), multiply(`doMul`) and divide(`doDiv`) 2 numbers, whichever their type may be.

```cpp
// FunctionPointers.hh
namespace FunctionPointers {
    class FunctionPointer {
        public:
            //// Operative functions ////
            template<typename T, typename U>
            T doAdd(T& a, U& b) { T res; return res = a + b; }

            template<typename T, typename U>
            T doSub(T& a, U& b) { T res; return res = a - b; }

            template<typename T, typename U>
            T doMUl(T& a, U& b) { T res; return res = a * b; }

            template<typename T, typename U>
            T doDiv(T& a, U& b) { 
                T res;
                if (b == 0) return false;
                return res = a / b; 
            }
    };
}
```

A use case would be:

```cpp
// FunctionPointers.cpp
#inlcude <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

FunctionPointers::FunctionPointer* FP = new FunctionPointers::FunctionPointer();

int main() {
    int a = 1; float b = 3.1415;

    cout << FP->doAdd(a, b) << endl;
    cout << FP->doSub(a, b) << endl;

    // Something the likes of this
    cout << FP->doOp(a, b, doAdd) << endl;

    return 1;
}
```

What is the best approach to such problem? Does a solution even exist that is compatible with the written header and main file?

Comment: Is there any problem with your code example you didn't state here?

Comment: You'll need to pass an appropriate member function pointer to `doOp()`. I think the easiest implementation for your case would be wrapping these into a lambda you can pass there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename F>
T doOp(T& a, U& b, F f)
{
    return std::invoke(f, this, a, b);
}
```

And then

```
int main() {
    FunctionPointers::FunctionPointer FP;
    int a = 1; float b = 3.1415;

    std::cout << FP.doAdd(a, b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << FP.doSub(a, b) << std::endl;

    // Something the likes of this
    std::cout << FP.doOp(a, b, &FunctionPointers::FunctionPointer::doAdd<int, float>) << std::endl;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Kf8G6oTo)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is sending the address to the member function template you want to call, but then you might as well just call it directly.

Another thing you could do is having some flags, ex:

```
enum class op {
    add, sub, mul, div
};
```

and then a function to handle the flags

```
template <auto O, class A, class B>
auto doOp(A a, B b)
{
    switch (O) {
        case op::add: return doAdd(a, b);
        case op::sub: return doSub(a, b);
        case op::mul: return doMUl(a, b);
        case op::div: return doDiv(a, b);
    }
}
```

and use it like so

```
FunctionPointers::FunctionPointer FP;
std::cout << FP.doOp<op::add>(a, b);
```

---

But then you might as well just do

```
namespace FunctionPointers {
class FunctionPointer {
public:
    // ...
    template <class T, class A, class B>
    auto Do(A a, B b)
    {
        return T{}.operator()(a, b);
    }
};
} // namespace FunctionPointers

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    float b = 3.1415;

    FunctionPointers::FunctionPointer FP;
    cout << FP.Do<std::divides<>>(a, b);
}
```